# Unspecified error with Turbolinks in Outlook and IE11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-11, outlook-addin, turbolinks

We're getting `unspecified error` in our Outlook Add-In that uses IE as its browser engine. The error comes from our compiled application.js javascript file that traces into Turbolinks.

This error occurs when we load our application in our Outlook add-in integration. There is a loading page that determines if the user needs to log in, and if not, will redirect them into our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those bugs you bang your head on for days or weeks and then it turns out to be a one line fix.

TLDR;

`window.location.replace(url)` is dangerous as it doesn't update history. This means the user won't be able to click the back button. But also, it means with frameworks like Turbolinks that manipulate history you have to be careful.

Instead, use:
`window.location.assign(url)`

The long story:
In our Outlook Add-In's landing page that determines whether to prompt for login or redirect to the application, we were using `window.location.replace`. For some reason (that I can't fully explain) when our application loads, there is Turbolinks processing that tries to call "replaceState" on the window's history object.

For some reason, when the first page you access, redirects with `replace`, there is an empty history that causes `unspecified error` in IE.

The fix is simply to do a proper history adding redirect using `location.assign(url)`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes, I tried to, but have to wait the 48hrs. Will do once the time has elapsed